# Running npm in cmd giving me errors, I just installed nodejs msi on windows

Tags: node.js, npm

I installed `nodejs` in Windows system from official website and `npm` giving errors:

```
CALL "C:\Program Files\node js\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not
recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

---

I have given all sorts of paths. Please help me.

http://prntscr.com/gso39z

Answer (score 1):

Add the following paths to your PATH environment variable

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

(note that i have windows 10, where your programs are installed can differ as per your windows version)

To permanently set PATH environment variable, follow these steps:

1. This PC/ My Computer Properties
2. Advanced System Settings, (right side)
3. from popup, click environment variable
4. select PATH environment variable under **system variable, (not user variable)** then click edit
5. Click new, and copy and paste one of the path (given) there.
6. new again and paste second path

to check if its set or not, goto terminal, and type `PATH`

**note:** if you type `PATH`, its value will be displayed, but if you type `%PATH%` , each of its value will act as a command input to terminal (windows terminal -_-).

Comment: thanks for answer but  still problem,   'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: You use node by typing `node <script-file>` in the terminal. For using `npm` (Node Package manager), type npm. type node --help or click [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

Start the process by being an **administrator**.
Open up your command prompt as an administrator.

And if you are using older version of node say 6.9, please upgrade to 6.10, it may solve your problem.